# How can I run a function on EVERY user action?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, settimeout

I'm working on a React Native kiosk app that will run on an Android tablet mounted on a wall. We'd like to implement a "screen saver" kind of feature — if the user hasn't touched the screen in 30 seconds, we want to fade to a nice looking splash screen, then switch back to the main UI when the touch the screen.

I'm having trouble with resetting the "screen saver" countdown timer. On the web, I'd handle this with a click or mousemove handler near the root of the app that dispatches any time the user does anything, something like...

```
let timeout = setTimeout(startScreenSaver, 30000);
document.body.addEventListener("click", () => {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  setTimeout(startScreenSaver, 30000);
});
```

Is there a way to do something similar in React Native?

Comment: How about you make a component for the screensaver. Once the screensaver is activated you navigate to the screensaver-component. That component is wrapped within a <TouchableWithoutFeedback>. Then you navigate back onPress to your main-screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `onTouchStart` prop on the root view component, the event comes whenever you touch the view.

For example,

```
onTouchStart = () => {
   clearTimeout(timeout);
   setTimeout(startScreenSaver, 30000);
}

render() {
  <View onTouchStart={this.onTouchStart}>
    ...
  </View>
}
```